# Interpolation of the grid obtained from different calculations

Tags: interpolation

I have a function that takes a lot of time to calculate. So I want to do Interpolation of the function. In different ranges of function parameters, I want to calculate grids with different steps, then join the grids and then use Interpolation. But Mathematica gives error:

`Interpolation::indim: The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid.`

Is this error related precisely to the fact that I use a different grid spacing? Is there a way to get a function by interpolation having a grid with different steps for this?

Example:
A gril 1 from the first calculation:

```
P1={{{0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3}, 4.96535}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4}, 
  4.74516}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5}, 4.56691}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6}, 
  4.41883}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7}, 4.29208}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8}, 
  4.18107}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9}, 4.08194}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3}, 
  4.74516}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4}, 4.53962}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5}, 
  4.37341}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6}, 4.23488}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7}, 
  4.11593}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8}, 4.01236}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9}, 
  3.9204}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3}, 4.56691}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4}, 
  4.37341}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5}, 4.21562}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6}, 
  4.08258}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7}, 3.97067}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8}, 
  3.87224}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9}, 3.78482}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3}, 
  4.41883}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4}, 4.23488}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5}, 
  4.08258}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6}, 3.95683}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7}, 
  3.84815}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8}, 3.75359}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9}, 
  3.67031}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3}, 4.29208}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4}, 
  4.11593}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.5}, 3.97067}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6}, 
  3.84815}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7}, 3.74314}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8}, 
  3.65211}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9}, 3.57176}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.3}, 
  4.18107}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.4}, 4.01236}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.5}, 
  3.87224}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6}, 3.75359}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7}, 
  3.65211}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8}, 3.56584}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9}, 
  3.48566}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.3}, 4.08194}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4}, 
  3.9204}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.5}, 3.78482}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.6}, 
  3.67031}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.7}, 3.57176}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.8}, 
  3.48566}, {{0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9}, 3.40951}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, 
  4.30995}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4}, 4.12532}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5}, 
  3.9689}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.6}, 3.83364}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7}, 
  3.71488}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8}, 3.60897}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9}, 
  3.51319}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3}, 4.12414}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4}, 
  3.95558}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5}, 3.81216}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6}, 
  3.6888}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7}, 3.58121}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8}, 
  3.48476}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9}, 3.39773}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3}, 
  3.97481}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4}, 3.81503}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5}, 
  3.67828}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6}, 3.56588}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7}, 
  3.46541}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8}, 3.37599}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9}, 
  3.29457}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3}, 3.8468}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4}, 
  3.6967}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5}, 3.56801}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6}, 
  3.45938}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7}, 3.36476}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}, 
  3.27989}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.9}, 3.20389}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3}, 
  3.7383}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.4}, 3.59184}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5}, 
  3.47055}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6}, 3.36659}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7}, 
  3.27586}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.8}, 3.19544}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9}, 
  3.12413}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.3}, 3.64079}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4}, 
  3.50182}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5}, 3.38493}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6}, 
  3.2848}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7}, 3.19751}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8}, 
  3.1203}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9}, 3.05207}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3}, 
  3.55629}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4}, 3.42204}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.5}, 
  3.30919}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.6}, 3.21241}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.7}, 
  3.1282}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8}, 3.05297}, {{0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 0.9}, 
  2.98671}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3}, 3.78321}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4}, 
  3.61792}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5}, 3.47428}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6}, 
  3.34763}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.7}, 3.23363}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8}, 
  3.13189}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.9}, 3.03938}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3}, 
  3.63988}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4}, 3.49063}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5}, 
  3.36077}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6}, 3.24614}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7}, 
  3.14354}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8}, 3.05095}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.9}, 
  2.96656}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3}, 3.51622}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4}, 
  3.37894}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, 3.25945}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6}, 
  3.15409}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7}, 3.05975}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8}, 
  2.97462}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9}, 2.8966}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3}, 
  3.40911}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4}, 3.28112}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5}, 
  3.16956}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6}, 3.07116}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7}, 
  2.98318}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8}, 2.90384}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9}, 
  2.83106}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3}, 3.31541}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4}, 
  3.19448}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5}, 3.08917}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6}, 
  2.99641}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7}, 2.91366}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8}, 
  2.8387}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}, 2.7704}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3}, 
  3.23242}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4}, 3.11729}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5}, 
  3.01711}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6}, 2.92943}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7}, 
  2.85053}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.8}, 2.77907}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9}, 
  2.71426}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.3}, 3.15851}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.4}, 
  3.04839}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5}, 2.95273}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6}, 
  2.86751}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.7}, 2.79211}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8}, 
  2.7242}, {{0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9}, 2.66241}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3}, 
  3.31059}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.4}, 3.16368}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5}, 
  3.0322}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.6}, 2.91576}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7}, 
  2.8118}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8}, 2.71719}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.9}, 
  2.6311}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3}, 3.20951}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4}, 
  3.07697}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5}, 2.95869}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6}, 
  2.85222}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7}, 2.75627}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.8}, 
  2.66913}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.9}, 2.58947}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3}, 
  3.11757}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4}, 2.99637}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5}, 
  2.88777}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.6}, 2.78975}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.7}, 
  2.70108}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8}, 2.62025}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.9}, 
  2.54607}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3}, 3.03483}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4}, 
  2.92252}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5}, 2.82165}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6}, 
  2.7304}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7}, 2.64773}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8}, 
  2.5722}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9}, 2.50284}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3}, 
  2.96006}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4}, 2.8551}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5}, 
  2.7606}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6}, 2.6752}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7}, 
  2.59757}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8}, 2.52653}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9}, 
  2.46084}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3}, 2.89289}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4}, 
  2.7931}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5}, 2.70374}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6}, 
  2.623}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.7}, 2.54959}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8}, 
  2.4824}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9}, 2.42059}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.3}, 
  2.83075}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.4}, 2.7364}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5}, 
  2.65139}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.6}, 2.57498}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7}, 
  2.50493}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8}, 2.44113}, {{0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9}, 
  2.38234}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3}, 2.87503}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.4}, 
  2.74832}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5}, 2.63387}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6}, 
  2.53136}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7}, 2.43796}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8}, 
  2.35408}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9}, 2.27724}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3}, 
  2.81181}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4}, 2.69607}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5}, 
  2.59092}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6}, 2.49549}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7}, 
  2.40881}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8}, 2.32982}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.9}, 
  2.25753}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3}, 2.7499}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4}, 
  2.64328}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.5}, 2.54581}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.6}, 
  2.45701}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7}, 2.37598}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.8}, 
  2.30177}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.9}, 2.23358}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3}, 
  2.69123}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4}, 2.59234}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5}, 
  2.50145}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6}, 2.41834}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.7}, 
  2.34235}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8}, 2.27243}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.9}, 
  2.208}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3}, 2.63642}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4}, 
  2.54392}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5}, 2.45875}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6}, 
  2.3802}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7}, 2.30837}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8}, 
  2.24223}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9}, 2.18111}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.3}, 
  2.5848}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4}, 2.49779}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5}, 
  2.41736}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6}, 2.34342}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7}, 
  2.27537}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8}, 2.21258}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}, 
  2.15446}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.3}, 2.53685}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.4}, 
  2.45445}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5}, 2.37835}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.6}, 
  2.30826}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.7}, 2.24332}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8}, 
  2.18343}, {{0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9}, 2.12794}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3}, 
  2.48129}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4}, 2.37626}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5}, 
  2.27972}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6}, 2.19202}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7}, 
  2.11237}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.8}, 2.03988}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.9}, 
  1.97364}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3}, 2.44633}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.4}, 
  2.34847}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5}, 2.2581}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6}, 
  2.17549}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7}, 2.10001}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8}, 
  2.03095}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9}, 1.96759}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.3}, 
  2.40853}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.4}, 2.31739}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5}, 
  2.23315}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6}, 2.15476}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7}, 
  2.08321}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8}, 2.01745}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.9}, 
  1.95688}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3}, 2.37058}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4}, 
  2.28547}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5}, 2.20579}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6}, 
  2.13216}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.7}, 2.06428}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8}, 
  2.00151}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9}, 1.94361}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.3}, 
  2.3333}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.4}, 2.25318}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5}, 
  2.17796}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6}, 2.10814}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7}, 
  2.04352}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8}, 1.98371}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9}, 
  1.92837}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3}, 2.29744}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4}, 
  2.22178}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5}, 2.15045}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6}, 
  2.08413}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7}, 2.0225}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8}, 
  1.96534}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9}, 1.91218}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3}, 
  2.2629}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.4}, 2.19111}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.5}, 
  2.12336}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6}, 2.05995}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7}, 
  1.71571}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8}, 1.94634}, {{0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9}, 
  1.89534}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3}, 2.13357}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.4}, 
  2.04898}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.5}, 1.97005}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.6}, 
  1.89756}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.7}, 1.83136}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.8}, 
  1.77068}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.9}, 1.71503}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.3}, 
  2.11788}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.4}, 2.0377}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.5}, 
  1.96268}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6}, 1.89335}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.7}, 
  1.82959}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.8}, 1.7709}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.9}, 
  1.7169}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3}, 2.09777}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.5, 0.4}, 
  2.02211}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5}, 1.9508}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.5, 0.6}, 
  1.88458}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.5, 0.7}, 1.82334}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8}, 
  1.76687}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9}, 1.71458}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3}, 
  2.07602}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.4}, 2.00446}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.5}, 
  1.9367}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6}, 1.8733}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.7}, 
  1.81447}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8}, 1.75995}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.9}, 
  1.70945}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.3}, 2.05286}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.4}, 
  1.98502}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.5}, 1.92043}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.6}, 
  1.85988}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7}, 1.80341}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8}, 
  1.75086}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.7, 0.9}, 1.70206}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.3}, 
  2.02972}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.4}, 1.96529}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5}, 
  1.90358}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6}, 1.84547}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7}, 
  1.79123}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8}, 1.7406}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9}, 
  1.69343}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.3}, 2.00672}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.4}, 
  1.94524}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5}, 1.88612}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.6}, 
  1.83045}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.7}, 1.77818}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8}, 
  1.72937}, {{0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9}, 1.68376}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3}, 
  4.30995}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4}, 4.12414}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5}, 
  3.97481}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6}, 3.8468}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7}, 
  3.7383}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8}, 3.64079}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9}, 
  3.55629}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3}, 4.12532}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4}, 
  3.95558}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5}, 3.81503}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6}, 
  3.6967}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7}, 3.59184}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8}, 
  3.50182}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9}, 3.42204}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3}, 
  3.9689}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4}, 3.81216}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5}, 
  3.67828}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6}, 3.56801}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7}, 
  3.47055}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8}, 3.38493}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9}, 
  3.30919}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3}, 3.83364}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4}, 
  3.6888}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5}, 3.56588}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6}, 
  3.45938}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7}, 3.36659}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8}, 
  3.2848}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9}, 3.21241}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3}, 
  3.71488}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4}, 3.58121}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.5}, 
  3.46541}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6}, 3.36476}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.7}, 
  3.27586}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8}, 3.19751}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9}, 
  3.1282}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.3}, 3.60897}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.4}, 
  3.48476}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.5}, 3.37599}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6}, 
  3.27989}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7}, 3.19544}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8}, 
  3.1203}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9}, 3.05297}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.3}, 
  3.51319}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4}, 3.39773}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.5}, 
  3.29457}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.6}, 3.20389}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.7}, 
  3.12413}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.8}, 3.05207}, {{0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9}, 
  2.98671}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, 3.72583}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4}, 
  3.57387}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5}, 3.44702}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.6}, 
  3.33868}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7}, 3.24436}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8}, 
  3.16112}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9}, 3.08636}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3}, 
  3.57387}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4}, 3.43336}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5}, 
  3.31494}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6}, 3.21375}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7}, 
  3.12559}}
```

A gril 2 from the second calculation:

```
P2={{{1, 1, 1, 1}, 0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, 
  0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}, {{1, 1, 1, 41}, 
  0.31218}, {{1, 1, 1, 51}, 0.28283}, {{1, 1, 1, 61}, 
  0.260093}, {{1, 1, 1, 71}, 0.241748}, {{1, 1, 1, 81}, 
  0.226774}, {{1, 1, 1, 91}, 0.214025}, {{1, 1, 11, 1}, 
  0.512393}, {{1, 1, 11, 11}, 0.355455}, {{1, 1, 11, 21}, 
  0.305325}, {{1, 1, 11, 31}, 0.276893}, {{1, 1, 11, 41}, 
  0.256457}, {{1, 1, 11, 51}, 0.24069}, {{1, 1, 11, 61}, 
  0.227872}, {{1, 1, 11, 71}, 0.216822}, {{1, 1, 11, 81}, 
  0.207313}, {{1, 1, 11, 91}, 0.198984}, {{1, 1, 21, 1}, 
  0.410614}, {{1, 1, 21, 11}, 0.305325}, {{1, 1, 21, 21}, 
  0.263447}, {{1, 1, 21, 31}, 0.240124}, {{1, 1, 21, 41}, 
  0.224134}, {{1, 1, 21, 51}, 0.21206}, {{1, 1, 21, 61}, 
  0.202523}, {{1, 1, 21, 71}, 0.194094}, {{1, 1, 21, 81}, 
  0.18712}, {{1, 1, 21, 91}, 0.180969}, {{1, 1, 31, 1}, 
  0.351969}, {{1, 1, 31, 11}, 0.276893}, {{1, 1, 31, 21}, 
  0.240124}, {{1, 1, 31, 31}, 0.219001}, {{1, 1, 31, 41}, 
  0.204972}, {{1, 1, 31, 51}, 0.194129}, {{1, 1, 31, 61}, 
  0.185988}, {{1, 1, 31, 71}, 0.178547}, {{1, 1, 31, 81}, 
  0.173333}, {{1, 1, 31, 91}, 0.16751}, {{1, 1, 41, 1}, 
  0.31218}, {{1, 1, 41, 11}, 0.256457}, {{1, 1, 41, 21}, 
  0.224134}, {{1, 1, 41, 31}, 0.204972}, {{1, 1, 41, 41}, 
  0.191585}, {{1, 1, 41, 51}, 0.183077}, {{1, 1, 41, 61}, 
  0.173049}, {{1, 1, 41, 71}, 0.167547}, {{1, 1, 41, 81}, 
  0.162071}, {{1, 1, 41, 91}, 0.157381}, {{1, 1, 51, 1}, 
  0.28283}, {{1, 1, 51, 11}, 0.24069}, {{1, 1, 51, 21}, 
  0.21206}, {{1, 1, 51, 31}, 0.194129}, {{1, 1, 51, 41}, 
  0.183077}, {{1, 1, 51, 51}, 0.172066}, {{1, 1, 51, 61}, 
  0.165061}, {{1, 1, 51, 71}, 0.158856}, {{1, 1, 51, 81}, 
  0.153048}, {{1, 1, 51, 91}, 0.149414}, {{1, 1, 61, 1}, 
  0.260093}, {{1, 1, 61, 11}, 0.227872}, {{1, 1, 61, 21}, 
  0.202523}, {{1, 1, 61, 31}, 0.185988}, {{1, 1, 61, 41}, 
  0.173049}, {{1, 1, 61, 51}, 0.165061}, {{1, 1, 61, 61}, 
  0.160349}, {{1, 1, 61, 71}, 0.151958}, {{1, 1, 61, 81}, 
  0.147147}, {{1, 1, 61, 91}, 0.143122}, {{1, 1, 71, 1}, 
  0.241748}, {{1, 1, 71, 11}, 0.216822}, {{1, 1, 71, 21}, 
  0.194094}, {{1, 1, 71, 31}, 0.178547}, {{1, 1, 71, 41}, 
  0.167547}, {{1, 1, 71, 51}, 0.158856}, {{1, 1, 71, 61}, 
  0.151958}, {{1, 1, 71, 71}, 0.146496}, {{1, 1, 71, 81}, 
  0.141764}, {{1, 1, 71, 91}, 0.138085}, {{1, 1, 81, 1}, 
  0.226774}, {{1, 1, 81, 11}, 0.207313}, {{1, 1, 81, 21}, 
  0.18712}, {{1, 1, 81, 31}, 0.173333}, {{1, 1, 81, 41}, 
  0.162071}, {{1, 1, 81, 51}, 0.153048}, {{1, 1, 81, 61}, 
  0.147147}, {{1, 1, 81, 71}, 0.141764}, {{1, 1, 81, 81}, 
  0.137571}, {{1, 1, 81, 91}, 0.133541}, {{1, 1, 91, 1}, 
  0.214025}, {{1, 1, 91, 11}, 0.198984}, {{1, 1, 91, 21}, 
  0.180969}, {{1, 1, 91, 31}, 0.16751}, {{1, 1, 91, 41}, 
  0.157381}, {{1, 1, 91, 51}, 0.149414}, {{1, 1, 91, 61}, 
  0.143122}, {{1, 1, 91, 71}, 0.138085}, {{1, 1, 91, 81}, 
  0.133541}, {{1, 1, 91, 91}, 0.129784}, {{1, 2, 1, 1}, 
  0.463533}, {{1, 2, 1, 11}, 0.277086}, {{1, 2, 1, 21}, 
  0.212019}, {{1, 2, 1, 31}, 0.176913}, {{1, 2, 1, 41}, 
  0.154064}, {{1, 2, 1, 51}, 0.137829}, {{1, 2, 1, 61}, 
  0.125703}, {{1, 2, 1, 71}, 0.116392}, {{1, 2, 1, 81}, 
  0.108761}, {{1, 2, 1, 91}, 0.102453}, {{1, 2, 11, 1}, 
  0.319562}, {{1, 2, 11, 11}, 0.236712}, {{1, 2, 11, 21}, 
  0.197066}, {{1, 2, 11, 31}, 0.171932}, {{1, 2, 11, 41}, 
  0.154573}, {{1, 2, 11, 51}, 0.140578}, {{1, 2, 11, 61}, 
  0.129777}, {{1, 2, 11, 71}, 0.121027}, {{1, 2, 11, 81}, 
  0.113758}, {{1, 2, 11, 91}, 0.107458}, {{1, 2, 21, 1}, 
  0.268994}, {{1, 2, 21, 11}, 0.208538}, {{1, 2, 21, 21}, 
  0.179346}, {{1, 2, 21, 31}, 0.160026}, {{1, 2, 21, 41}, 
  0.14591}, {{1, 2, 21, 51}, 0.134836}, {{1, 2, 21, 61}, 
  0.125811}, {{1, 2, 21, 71}, 0.119021}, {{1, 2, 21, 81}, 
  0.112156}, {{1, 2, 21, 91}, 0.106446}, {{1, 2, 31, 1}, 
  0.240794}, {{1, 2, 31, 11}, 0.192159}, {{1, 2, 31, 21}, 
  0.166114}, {{1, 2, 31, 31}, 0.150097}, {{1, 2, 31, 41}, 
  0.138223}, {{1, 2, 31, 51}, 0.128887}, {{1, 2, 31, 61}, 
  0.121138}, {{1, 2, 31, 71}, 0.11479}, {{1, 2, 31, 81}, 
  0.109682}, {{1, 2, 31, 91}, 0.104264}, {{1, 2, 41, 1}, 
  0.221953}, {{1, 2, 41, 11}, 0.177774}, {{1, 2, 41, 21}, 
  0.155766}, {{1, 2, 41, 31}, 0.141355}, {{1, 2, 41, 41}, 
  0.131098}, {{1, 2, 41, 51}, 0.123344}, {{1, 2, 41, 61}, 
  0.118701}, {{1, 2, 41, 71}, 0.110858}, {{1, 2, 41, 81}, 
  0.105983}, {{1, 2, 41, 91}, 0.101513}, {{1, 2, 51, 1}, 
  0.208764}, {{1, 2, 51, 11}, 0.168175}, {{1, 2, 51, 21}, 
  0.147542}, {{1, 2, 51, 31}, 0.135094}, {{1, 2, 51, 41}, 
  0.125826}, {{1, 2, 51, 51}, 0.120732}, {{1, 2, 51, 61}, 
  0.112242}, {{1, 2, 51, 71}, 0.107376}, {{1, 2, 51, 81}, 
  0.102836}, {{1, 2, 51, 91}, 0.0987615}, {{1, 2, 61, 1}, 
  0.197266}, {{1, 2, 61, 11}, 0.16073}, {{1, 2, 61, 21}, 
  0.141486}, {{1, 2, 61, 31}, 0.129716}, {{1, 2, 61, 41}, 
  0.121076}, {{1, 2, 61, 51}, 0.11436}, {{1, 2, 61, 61}, 
  0.10886}, {{1, 2, 61, 71}, 0.104711}, {{1, 2, 61, 81}, 
  0.0998439}, {{1, 2, 61, 91}, 0.0959502}, {{1, 2, 71, 1}, 
  0.188258}, {{1, 2, 71, 11}, 0.154428}, {{1, 2, 71, 21}, 
  0.136257}}
```

Next I Join P1 and P2 to the P an then try use Interpolation:

```
P = Join[P1, P2];
PP=Interpolation[P];
```

Finaly, Mathematica gives error:

`Interpolation::indim: The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid.`

Comment: Related: [Working around Error: Interpolation on unstructured grids using Sort for 4D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258884/working-around-error-interpolation-on-unstructured-grids-using-sort-for-4d-data)

Comment: My grids are full (not only {x,x,x,z} plane), but I can't add full grids here because they are very big. The error message still remains.

Comment: I realized after posting the comment that there are more issues in 4D, which is why I also deleted my comment - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added more elements to the grids, but not all, because there is limit

Comment: did you take a look at the answer in the linked question? Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, I studied information in the link. Interpolation methods presented in the link, don't work for my grids. Method -> "Voronoi" even didn't run, Method -> "RBF" can be run, but the error massage appears `LinearSolve::luc: Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix {<<1>>} may contain significant numerical errors`

Comment: I meant the question I linked in my comment above (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258884/working-around-error-interpolation-on-unstructured-grids-using-sort-for-4d-data) - what question are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, I followed the link (mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258884/…)  and then used information from the link (familydahl.se/mathematica) from this massage: You may try Obtuse package: familydahl.se/mathematica For your example "PolyharmonicSplineInterpolation" shown by Ted seems to be a better choice though.

Answer (score 1):

The first three coordinates of your data are all equal and you only consider two different sets `{.3,.3,.3,...},{1,1,1,...}`! That causes the error I think.

Knowing x1==x2==x3 in your coordinatespace {x1,x2,x3,x4} it's obvious to reduce the dimension from 4 to 2.

For a twodimensional interpolation  it works with `InterpolationOrder->1`

```
ip = Map[{{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, -1]]}, #[[2]]} &, P] //Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] &
Plot3D[ip[x, y], {x, .3, 1}, {y, .3, 41}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I added more elements to the grids, now I I am dealing with a 4D.